Swift Core Data fetch request with inconsistent behavior
I'm currently working on Unit Tests and need to check Core Data operations. I have the following Core Data entry in the database:
<EasyFPU.FoodItem: 0x6000021b00f0> (entity: FoodItem; id: 0x6000002a02c0 <x-coredata://55F63A9D-9195-4991-8B24-8A3FF6301B1E/FoodItem/p6>; data: {
    caloriesPer100g = 72;
    carbsPer100g = "10.4";
    category = Product;
    composedFoodItem = nil;
    favorite = 0;
    id = "220458AD-3216-45A2-9FC3-32285A2A36D0";
    ingredients =     (
    );
    name = Alpenzwerg;
    sugarsPer100g = "9.4";
    typicalAmounts =     (
    );
})

I can get this entry by its name, using the following function:
static func getFoodItemByName(name: String) -> FoodItem? {
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name == %@", name)
    let request: NSFetchRequest<FoodItem> = FoodItem.fetchRequest()
    request.predicate = predicate
    if let result = try? CoreDataStack.viewContext.fetch(request) {
        if !result.isEmpty {
            return result[0]
        }
    }
    return nil
}

Works perfectly fine. However, when trying to achieve the same by using the id instead of name, it fails.
static func getFoodItemByID(_ id: String) -> FoodItem? {
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id == %@", id)
    let request: NSFetchRequest<FoodItem> = FoodItem.fetchRequest()
    request.predicate = predicate
    if let result = try? CoreDataStack.viewContext.fetch(request) {
        if !result.isEmpty {
            return result[0]
        }
    }
    return nil
}

The result returned by the fetch request is empty (0 values).
This is my data model:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<model type="com.apple.IDECoreDataModeler.DataModel" documentVersion="1.0" lastSavedToolsVersion="23231" systemVersion="24A335" minimumToolsVersion="Automatic" sourceLanguage="Swift" usedWithCloudKit="YES" userDefinedModelVersionIdentifier="">
    <entity name="FoodItem" representedClassName=".FoodItem" syncable="YES">
        <attribute name="caloriesPer100g" attributeType="Double" defaultValueString="0.0" usesScalarValueType="YES"/>
        <attribute name="carbsPer100g" attributeType="Double" defaultValueString="0.0" usesScalarValueType="YES"/>
        <attribute name="category" optional="YES" attributeType="String"/>
        <attribute name="favorite" attributeType="Boolean" defaultValueString="NO" usesScalarValueType="YES"/>
        <attribute name="id" optional="YES" attributeType="UUID" usesScalarValueType="NO"/>
        <attribute name="name" optional="YES" attributeType="String"/>
        <attribute name="sugarsPer100g" attributeType="Double" defaultValueString="0.0" usesScalarValueType="YES"/>
        <relationship name="composedFoodItem" optional="YES" maxCount="1" deletionRule="Nullify" destinationEntity="ComposedFoodItem" inverseName="foodItem" inverseEntity="ComposedFoodItem"/>
        <relationship name="ingredients" optional="YES" toMany="YES" deletionRule="Nullify" destinationEntity="Ingredient" inverseName="foodItem" inverseEntity="Ingredient"/>
        <relationship name="typicalAmounts" optional="YES" toMany="YES" deletionRule="Cascade" destinationEntity="TypicalAmount" inverseName="foodItem" inverseEntity="TypicalAmount"/>
    </entity>
</model>

Any ideas? It's exactly the same code using exactly the same database. Thanks!

The obvious cause would be an error in the id you are fetching by.  Also, try ? should be avoided.  You should do/try/catch and at least log any error that is thrown.

Thanks, @Paulw11, I'm now catching errors, but none are thrown. I also made sure I'm using the correct id in my NSPredicate. Could it be that the id I'm looking for is confused with the id of the entity in the first line of the data?

How is the id attribute defined?

Thanks, @JoakimDanielson, this was the right hint! The id is stored as UUID and not as String, and I have been requesting it as String. I will update my question above with the right fetch method.

Solved! I fetched the wrong data type. The correct implementation of the getFoodItemByID function must be:
static func getFoodItemByID(id: UUID) -> FoodItem? {
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id == %@", id as CVarArg)
    let request: NSFetchRequest<FoodItem> = FoodItem.fetchRequest()
    request.predicate = predicate
    do {
        let result = try CoreDataStack.viewContext.fetch(request)
        if !result.isEmpty {
            return result[0]
        }
    } catch {
        debugPrint("Error fetching food item: \(error)")
    }
    return nil
}

Kudos to @JoakimDanielson for the right hint!
